# Run maven command from docker image

Tags: java, maven, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am building a docker image inside gitlab runner.
So, I am using docker:latest image, because I need to push the image to the registry, but before building the image, I need to package my java project.
How to use docker image with maven to build project?

Right now, gitlab runner returns an error

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd)":/opt/maven -w /opt/maven maven:3.3.9-jdk-8 mvn clean install
the input device is not a TTY
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need (and cannot) `run` the container as interactive nor allocate a TTY there in Gitlab. So remove the `-it` from your docker run:

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/opt/maven -w /opt/maven maven:3.3.9-jdk-8 mvn clean install
```

Comment: you're welcome! you can mark as [Accepted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwTL.png) if you consider it

Comment: But where I can find my war file after calling `mvn package`?

Comment: Just for troubleshooting do this: `docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/opt/maven -w /opt/maven maven:3.3.9-jdk-8 sh -c "mvn clean install; find / |grep NAME"` (put in NAME some part of the filename that you are searching)

Comment: I see only this
`[INFO] Assembling webapp [web] in [/opt/maven/web/target/web]`
`[INFO] Building war: /opt/maven/web/target/web.war`

Comment: So the war is in `$(pwd)/web/target/web.war` local to gitlab